# Is it possible to insert a new row using Query Language?

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm using this code:

```
select B, C, SUM(I) where K="yes" or K="maybe" group by B, C order by B asc
```

to take data from one table and sort it into another, where I'm using functions to calculate all sorts of different, annoyingly complicated things. Problem is, whenever new data is added, because I wanted it sorted alphabetically, it shifts rows down. Is it possible to add a new, entirely empty row, except for the data selected, when new data is added?

Comment: this kind of does not make sense how adding a row would solve shifting issue. can you provide some example as a scenario in the sheet?

Comment: Ok, I'll try my best. B contains names and C contains emails. Column I contains number of visits. After being shifted and the number of visits is summed up in the second column, a function divides them by 8 and adds the value in another column. Say you got John and Steve, then Mike comes along, Mike will have Steve's values on his row. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: here you go https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oahWjPEj8LSCESG0FYOUhHUD6xXYkweUclWExZDxwQY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It seems the formulas didn't get copied because I had to delete some sensitive information. It should be up to date now

Comment: the code is very dirty because I'm both new at this and I work alone, but the bottom line is, whenever values are added to the second sheet, column 6 checks against column 10. If the number is different, it sets the value from 5 to 10 and 6 to twelve. It's supposed to check of there's a free visit coming (thus the division by 8). Every time the total number of visits is updated, the total number of free visits and the total number of new free visits should get updated. It's messy but it's the only workaround I found for my problem

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to tell from your trimmed sheet where and what you need but, first thing first...

> Is it possible to insert a new row using Query Language?

if you mean if there is a syntax parameter to add row then no, there isn't. in `QUERY` you can add only artificial/empty columns (like: `=QUERY(A1:B3, "select A,' ',B label' '''", 0)`)

however, everything is possible so there are workarounds to construct the "adding the row" thing but that will hardly solve your misalignment issues. the thing you need is to either wrap your query formula into `VLOOKUP` or have a side table/sheet with variables and `VLOOKUP` them in. in both cases, you need to establish a common identificator so the stuff would align and pair up just the right way. for example:

[image: 0]

this way no matter what you add or remove from your query output, `VLOOKUP` will always inject the variables exactly where needed

[image]

Comment: Okay, thank you for taking the time to look into this, I will check VLOOKUP out.